# GROK Pattern for Exception stacktrace

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logback

This is my Exception Stacktrace

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-15] ERROR http-nio-8080-exec-15 SessionController error during login
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.abc.api.controller.SessionController.sessionAPI(SessionController.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

below GROK pattern i am using to parse above stacktrace

```
(\[%{DATA:thread}\])? %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{USERNAME:host} %{JAVAFILE:javaClass}%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}
```

below output is showing

```
{
  "thread": [
    [
      "http-nio-8080-exec-15"
    ]
  ],
  "level": [
    [
      "ERROR"
    ]
  ],
  "host": [
    [
      "http-nio-8080-exec-15"
    ]
  ],
  "javaClass": [
    [
      "SessionController"
    ]
  ],
  "logMessage": [
    [
      " error during login"
    ]
  ]
}
```

expected output should collect complete stacktrace as logMessage.
Below pattern i tried but no success

```
%{JAVASTACKTRACEPART:stacktrace}
```

Comment: You'd need to use the multiline codec to join the lines together, see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiline.html). Or you could join the lines together at the filebeat step if you're using it.

Comment: I am using multiline codec.

Comment: I have added below multiline codec and resolved my issue.
codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
            negate => true
            what => previous
            }